# How to create RewriteRule for space using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, web-deployment

I use htaccess for make mu URL clean. My original ULR is
http://localhost/bookStore/single_book.php?name=This%20is%20book%20no%204

i use php urlencode() function to make this

http://localhost/bookStore/single_book.php?name=This+is+book+no+4

but now i want to make this like:

http://localhost/bookStore/single_book/This+is+book+no+4

using htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^single_book/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) single_book.php?name=$2 [NC,L]
```

RewriteRule not working

Comment: So you have `/bookStore/single_book.php?name=This+is+book+no+4` and would like to replace `.php?name=` with `/`, correct?

Comment: Yes, i want to replace like this :   bookStore/single_book/This+is+book+no+4

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.+)
RewriteRule ^(bookStore/single_book)(\.php)$ $1/%1?
```

This matches if `name` is in the query string and if the `name` is the only portion of the query string.

I tested on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

And for playing with the regex, i used https://regexr.com/

The trailing `?` in the RewriteRule removes the query string.

Comment: sorry i don't understand can you give me the full RewriteRule like : ^single_book/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) single_book.php?name=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: Answer udpated and [here is my updated test](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=43a788bb-7cd2-59f7-9c06-faeb0489c342). Is this what you need? With it being more specific?

Comment: RewriteEngine on;
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.+);
RewriteRule ^(bookStore/single_book)(\.php)$ $1/%1?; i write like this but not working

Comment: Do you have other rewrite rules? Can you post the full `.htaccess` file?

Comment: And are you testing with the first url (containing `%20`) or are you testing with the second url (containing `+`)? I was writing a rule to match the second url (containing `+`).